# upload image file to dot net core 2 controller using apache cordova plugin file transfer

Tags: javascript, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, file-transfer, apache-cordova

Heres what I have so far in my controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("addexpenses")]
        public ActionResult AddExpenses(IFormFile _expenses)
        {
            Expenses expensesAhYeah = new Expenses();
            expensesAhYeah.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(_expenses["UserId"].ToString());
            expensesAhYeah.ExpenseType = Convert.ToInt32(_expenses["ExpenseType"].ToString());
            expensesAhYeah.ExpenseAmount = Convert.ToInt32(_expenses["ExpenseAmount"].ToString());
            expensesAhYeah.ExpenseDesc = _expenses["ExpenseDesc"].ToString();
            expensesAhYeah.ExpenseDate = Convert.ToDateTime(_expenses["ExpenseDate"].ToString());
            if (ModelState.IsValid) uRepo.AddNewExpense(expensesAhYeah);
            return Ok("ok");
        }
```

and for my apache cordova app

```
function saveExpenseReport() {
    var uctxt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ucontext'));
    var Expenses = JSON.stringify({
        'UserId': uctxt.idEmployee,
        'ExpenseType': $('#selExpenseType').val(),
        'ExpenseAmount': $('#expenseAmount').val(),
        'ExpenseDesc': $('#expenseReason').val(),
        'ExpenseDate': $('#expenseDate').val()
    });
    var fileURL = imgLoc;
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = "thisfilenamewew.jpg";
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    setLoading('show');
    options.params = Expenses;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    var encURI = encodeURI(apicall + "tjb/addexpenses");
    ft.upload(fileURL, encURI, win, fail, options);}
```

I code using vs2017 and dotnet core2, so I debug the webapi2 and have a breakpoint at the start of the controller. Why is my `_expenses` null?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried console writing the values from the json data you're populating? `$('#selExpenseType').val()` also `document.getElementById("selExpenseType").value;` is faster. Though debugging should consist of echoing and using the console.

Comment: Hello @EasyBB I did, its fine, thats not my concern right now. Before the `ft.upload` line I watch the value for `Expenses` and I got the correct values. the `_expenses` in the controller is null which is my problem.

Comment: Well from the looks of it you're passing all options to the controller and your expenses would be under expenses.options. And wouldn't you have to convert that string into json in the controller. Have you echoed the _expenses before doing anything with it. Just trying to piece this together programmatically for you

Comment: @EasyBB yes I did, and its not null, but when I hit the breakpoint at the controller, its null. What am I missing? some settings needs to be done with my controller? or the whole project?

Comment: Hitting the breakpoint point and it being null just may mean it hasn't populated asynchronous and may be populated the next step. It's been some time since I've worked with this, but work break it down step by step, only adding the next step until you're sure the previous is solid.

Comment: Hey I know it's too late to answer but if someone having the same problem they might get help from this link. I found a good article. [link](https://www.ttmind.com/TechPost/Cordova-Upload-Images-using-File-Transfer-Plugin-and-Net-core-WebAPI)